# How detect process open with no mistakes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, process

I'm conducting a routine that allows user to open files and encode them as soon they're closed.

To detect when the file is open AND when the file is already closed, I monitor processes search for its name (received by parameter Argument_Name):

```
    Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()

    Try
        For Each p As Process In processes
            Dim windows As IDictionary(Of IntPtr, String) = GetOpenWindowsFromPID(p.Id)
            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of IntPtr, String) In windows
                If kvp.ToString.Contains(Argument_Name) Then
                    return true
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Try

    return false
```

I check the name with and without extension, since some applications seems to report it in Process-List differently - some puts the entire name and extension while other puts only the name.

**My problem:**

1- My user opened an Office file called "x.docx"

2- It seems Word had saved only the main name "x"- maybe because the document TITLE is just "x" (the title you can define within document properties when "save as")

3- So, because of Office, in the above code I've to check just names withou extensions and/or path (*kvp.ToString.Contains()*).

Using this logic, I get WRONG results because ANY process with a "x" letter in name will be pointed as the true "x.docx".

**QUESTION:**

- How can I detect without any mistake the opened process from my application?
- How can I detect if a process is related to a filename without that colateral effect?

Do you have any idea to make it better?

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Why a negative vote without *any* reason about it?

Comment: WinRAR does precisely this behaviour. First when you save the file in the external application, it diplays the notice that the file won't be saved if close WinRAR, then when you close the file, it promts you if you want to save it. Aside from using VB.NET, I see no issue with this question whatsoever.

Comment: I have no choice since working with secure documents. I must detect when user closes the file and in an usual environment the user is working with several docs - I cannot ask him to inform application whenever he closed the file, I must detect it automatically and without ANY "lock" test.

Comment: Some applications lock a file when working with it, some don't. From my quick test, it appears that Word does lock the file, while Notepad for example doesn't. In the first case, WinRAR shows both windows, while in the second, it only asks if you want to update the file. But that was just an example - what about simply encoding the file whenever it is updated on the disk?

Comment: I need a solution to check if the file was closed, not necessarily updated.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to know when a process opens or closes a specific file. And actually, I don't see why you need that. You could employ the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to find when a file changes. Depending on the process name or the window title seems to be far from reliable.

Comment: You can try opening a stream to the file with write permissions to check if some other process has it locked, but as I said, some process don't lock the file at all.

Comment: No, it's not an option and it does not solve the specific answer above. Thank you anyway @IllidanS4.